# tidyr spread changes values from numeric

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, spread

I am doing this with a similar dataset and am having the same problem:

```
example <- mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  count(manufacturer) %>%
  unique() %>%
  spread(manufacturer, n)
```

I need to combine column information after the spread, however the function is changing my numeric column 'n' into a column of unknown character. When I try to add the columns I get this error:

```
example <- mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer) %>%
  group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  count(manufacturer) %>%
  unique() %>%
  spread(manufacturer, n) %>%
  mutate(combination = 'ford'+'honda')
```

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Thanks for any help

Edit: 
As the comments said, removing the quotes solved the problem. However, my actual dataset has variable names with spaces (for final report aesthetics) so I needed to find a way to rectify this without simply removing the quotes. To do so I did this:

```
example <- mpg %>% 
mutate(manufacturer = ifelse(manufacturer == 'ford' | 
manufacturer == 'honda', "combination", manufacturer)) %>% 
select(manufacturer) %>% 
group_by(manufacturer) %>%
count(manufacturer) %>%
unique() %>%
spread(manufacturer, n)
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes around ford and Honda: `mutate(combination = ford+honda)`

Comment: What dataset are you working with? `mtcars`?

Comment: Can you try changing your last line to `mutate(combination = ford+honda)`?

Comment: @NelsonGon `mpg` appears to be the dataset included with ggplot2: `ggplot2::mpg`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick Then as suggested OP just needs to remove quotes.

Comment: @PatrickEgan From your post you believed the issue to be that spread had somehow changed the datatype in your data frame. When something like this happens your first course of action should be to confirm whether or not this was what actually happened. In this case you could run your code to just after the spread and then inspect the result. A simple `str(example)` would likely reveal that your data is still numeric and would point towards the problem being elsewhere.

Comment: So it worked when I took the quotes out, but my actual dataset has spaces and it wasn't working to remove the quotes in that instance. Therefore I did this to fix it : example <- mpg %>%
  mutate(manufacturer = ifelse(manufacturer == 'ford' |
                                 manufacturer == 'honda', "combination", manufacturer)) %>%
  select(manufacturer) %>%